# How to use Bootstrap in only one component in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an angular application with custom themes, most of the components don't require bootstrap so in my angular.json I included only the bootstrap.grid.css.

As the application was developed I am need of bootstrap but including it in angular.json is affecting styling in other components.

Is there any option to use bootstrap only in this particular component.

I tried this `@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";` in css file but did not help.

TIA   :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to the party but I encountered this problem not so long ago: the need of using Bootstrap styles in only one component.
To solve this, I went to [the Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/) and downloaded the compiled CSS files. I was only interested in the **bootstrap.min.css** file.
To load it in only one component, actually the top header of the web page (I needed to get up and running quickly with a collapbsable navbar), I added the file mentioned above in the **stylesUrl** prop. of my component decorator like so (you are free to put the Bootstrap css file elsewhere) =>

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    "./../../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "./header.component.css"
  ]
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Now, thanks to default view encapsulation, I can use all Bootstrap styles in the top section of my web app' and in this place only :)

Bear in mind though that even the minified Boostrap style sheet will raise an error if you didnt modify your **angular.json** file the day you will run **ng build --prod** to deploy your app'; the reason is that, by default, budgets for components styles are set to a low maximum value for performance reasons.

So, in your **angular.json**, look for the **budgets** array and, in there, set a rule for your components styles that suits your needs, you will be interested in particular in the **maximumError** value, that might prevent you from doing your prod. build if you load large style sheets in a given component =>

```json
   ...
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "145kb"
                }
              ]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My trivial solution would be to insert the content of the bootstrap file to component CSS file, but this is only my opinion, not sure is it right.